# Empty response from Admin API abilities endpoint

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

I'm trying to get user abilities via the admin API and can't seem to get any content in the response for most accounts. I can get a response from one account that I've been testing with (x-request-id: 4a451da8b69c9beb5ba115ace51df75f). However for every other account, the response is empty (x-request-id: 1f46a6ba7fe025d001cb58ee30ff5431).

Here is the endpoint I'm trying to hit: https://banno.com/a/mobile/api/v0/institutions/xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx/users/xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx/abilities

Below is the response content I get back for the account that works:

```
"bill_pay_sync":false,"institution_id":"xxxxxxxx","p2p_enabled":true,"
                rdc":false,"user_id":"xxxxxxxx"
```

Which is expected - the important piece I want for each account is the rdc status

And below is the response content I get back for every other account:

```
{}
```

I find this odd considering RDC is enabled for the account providing no response content, but I'm not seeing any abilities.

With all that said, is there anything I/Banno can do to provide all of the user abilities in the user specific abilities endpoint?

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, we'll share that information with Engineering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for this endpoint should probably be updated to be more clear. However, I believe this is the expected behavior.

> Lookup the abilities for the given user at a given institution. In the general case, a user's ability set will be similar (if not identical) to that of the institution abilities, however this is never guaranteed. Any and all of a given user's abilities can be overridden such that they are completely different than the institution level abilities.

This endpoint will return any ability overrides for that specific user at the institution. An empty response of `{}` can be considered to mean that the user has the default abilities for the institution (see https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/admin-api/api-reference/v0/abilities/details/#/Institution%20Abilities/get_a_mobile_api_v0_institutions__institutionId__abilities).